# C++: "Multi-character character constant" warning when reading from a file into char array

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream input;
    input.open("kr.txt");
    int n;
    input >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        char line[16];
        input.ignore(256, '/n');
        input.get(eil, 16);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I get the warning at the "input.ignore()".
My file looks like this. 15 spaces separate the beginning of the line to the first number.

```
2
Rimas          195.5 45
Robertas       165 13
```

Comment: What's `'/n'`? It isn't the newline symbol.

Comment: I was getting the same thing with '/0'. Turned out its '\0', as @gordan.sikic answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/n` is constant consisting of two chars, `'/'` and `'n'`and you are not quoting it as a string, using `"`, but as a char, using `'`, hence warning.

Maybe you wanted to use backslash instead of slash, i.e. `'\n'`?

Comment: Yep, as ForceBru replied to the question, my problem is that I can't tell the difference between "/n" and "\n"